# Save view layer to image with renderInContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiimage

I am attempting to save my tableView layer as an image, and everything is working as expected.

However, it will only save the portion of the tableView that is actually visible on the view; if the tableView is longer than the display (and you have to scroll down to see it) that part is not saved in the created image

I'm sure I've overlooked something in here that doesn't allow it to save any portion outside what is currently in view. I'd appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);

[self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *imageView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two approaches to this, some better than others, with pros and cons each.

If you table view does not grow to a huge size, you can resize it to its content size, render and then restore it to its original size. This is easy, but as more and more cells are added to the table view, so does memory pressure and CPU usage as you resize the table view, because all cells need to be loaded and prepared for display.

Another option is to slice the content into several tiles, and join the tiles at the end, but setting the content offset of the table view to first page, second page, etc. This conserves memory but not CPU, as you still need to configure the cells. Also, you have a harder task to stitch the pieces together, taking into account content offset.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to just do custom drawing of all necessary contents into your context instead of making screenshots. That might be complicated, but at least you don't rely on UI hacks. Also, with this approach you can perform drawing on different thread - so your app won't freeze for some time - which can be quite noticeable when table view is big.

Anyway, i don't recommend you to modify your current table view parameters for making screenshot - better create additional table view for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
```

This method return a **Bitmap** with the options you passed it.

First param is *size* and, the final bitmap size in **pixel** is the *size* value, multiplied for the *scale* factor (in your case **0.0f**, that it means **1.0f** in your case).
So, preparing the context with this bitmap size, you will never get the **entire** tableView bitmap.

Try modifying the *size* parameter passing it `self.tableView.bounds.size`

> [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
>
> To get the size of the bitmap in pixels, you must multiply the width and height values by the value in the scale parameter.